# ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am using CSV dataset with 1 feature column (string) and 97 label columns (multi-label classification) with 1 or 0 for every row.
Data:

```
|    | vectorizer_input                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |   10 |   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |   29 |   30 |   31 |   32 |   33 |   34 |   35 |   36 |   37 |   38 |   39 |   40 |   41 |   42 |   43 |   44 |   45 |   46 |   47 |   48 |   49 |   50 |   51 |   52 |   53 |   54 |   55 |   56 |   57 |   58 |   59 |   60 |   61 |   62 |   63 |   64 |   65 |   66 |   67 |   68 |   69 |   70 |   71 |   72 |   73 |   74 |   75 |   76 |   77 |   78 |   79 |   80 |   81 |   82 |   83 |   84 |   85 |   86 |   87 |   88 |   89 |   90 |   91 |   92 |   93 |   94 |   95 |   96 |
|---:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|
|  0 | want improve question update question on-topic stack overflow closed 8 year ago json need update {activity_code1 activity_namefootball} {activity_code1 activity_nametennis} based activity_code achieve php first need decode change data re-encode save back file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  1 | string xml need return xml document default returned content type text plain content rendered need content type application xml enabled option respectbrowseracceptheader serialize object xml set correct content type except object string string xml need return xml document return contentresult controller startup project.json response github good measure                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  2 | volumetric imaging data consisting value sampled regular grid x z non-cubic voxel shape space adjacent point z greater x would eventually like able interpolate value arbitrary 2d plane pass volume like aware scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates case using le straightforward implicitly assumes spacing element input array equal across dimension could first resample input array according smallest voxel dimension voxels would cube use map_coordinates interpolate plane seem like great idea interpolate data twice also aware scipy various interpolators irregularly-spaced nd data linearndinterpolator nearestndinterpolator etc. slow memory-intensive purpose best way interpolating data given know value regularly spaced within dimension use map_coordinates little bit algebra let say spacing grid dx dy dz need map real world coordinate array index coordinate let define three new variable array index input map_coordinates array shape ... number dimension original data define array transform real world coordinate array index coordinate dividing scaling little broadcasting magic put together example let say want interpolate value along plane 2*y - z = 0 take two vector perpendicular plane normal vector get coordinate want interpolate convert array index coordinate interpoalte using map_coordinates last array shape 10 10 position [u_idx v_idx] value corresponding coordinate coords[ u_idx v_idx] could build idea handle interpolation coordinate start zero adding offset scaling |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  3 | best way calculate sum matrix a^i + a^ i+1 + a^i+2........a^n large n thought two possible way 1 use logarithmic matrix exponentiation lme a^i calculate subsequent matrix multiplying problem really take advantage lme algorithm using lowest power 2 use lme finding a^n memoize intermediate calculation problem much space required large n third way notice let logarithmic number step need compute inverse direct implementation lead log n ^2 factor keep log n computing power compute b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  4 | named color available matplotlib use plot find list matplotlib documentation claim name however found color also used least context list anyone know exhaustive list named color available constantly forget name color want use keep coming back question = previous answer great find bit difficult get overview available color posted image prefer color grouped similar color slightly tweaked matplotlib answer mentioned comment get color list sorted column order identical would sort eye think give good overview updated image code reflect arebeccapurple added three sage color moved xkcd prefix since posted answer originally really change much matplotlib example code completeness updated 2017-10-25 merged previous update section would like use additional named color plotting matplotlib use xkcd crowdsourced color name via xkcd prefix access plethora named color default tableau color available matplotlib via notab prefix ten distinct color also plot color html hex code similar specifying rgb tuple rather named color apart fact hex code passed string include image 16 million color choose from.. detail please refer matplotlib color documentation source file specifying available color _color_data.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Imports:

```py
import re
import tensorflow as tf
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from datasets import load_dataset
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, losses, metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

How I load the dataset:

```py
feature_cols = ['vectorizer_input']
label_cols = [str(i) for i in range(97)]

tfdataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    name,
    batch_size=128,
    column_names=feature_cols + label_cols,
    column_defaults=[tf.dtypes.string] + [tf.dtypes.int64] * 97,
    shuffle=False
)
```

Then I specify multiple label columns:

```py
def make_features_labels_tuple(x, feature_cols, label_cols):
    labels = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in label_cols}
    features = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in feature_cols}
    return features, labels

tfdataset = tfdataset.map(lambda x: make_features_labels_tuple(x, feature_cols, label_cols))
```

This is my simple model right now:

```py
vectorizer = layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=4000, output_sequence_length=4000)

model = models.Sequential(
    [
        vectorizer,
        layers.Embedding(4000, 64),
        layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(),
        layers.Dense(97, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[metrics.Accuracy(), metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()]
)
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 text_vectorization_44 (Text  (None, 4000)             0         
 Vectorization)                                                  
                                                                 
 embedding_16 (Embedding)    (None, 4000, 64)          256000    
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling1d_16 (Gl  (None, 64)               0         
 obalMaxPooling1D)                                               
                                                                 
 dense_16 (Dense)            (None, 97)                6305      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 262,305
Trainable params: 262,305
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And this is error I get when I try `model.fit`:

```
ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output: dict_keys(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96']). Valid mode output names: ['dense_7']. Received struct is: {'0': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '1': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '2': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:13' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '3': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:24' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '4': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:35' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '5': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:46' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '6': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:57' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '7': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:68' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '8': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:79' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '9': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:90' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '10': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '11': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '12': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '13': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '14': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '15': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:8' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '16': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:9' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '17': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:10' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '18': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:11' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '19': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:12' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '20': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:14' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '21': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:15' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '22': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:16' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '23': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:17' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '24': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:18' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '25': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:19' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '26': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:20' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '27': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:21' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '28': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:22' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '29': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:23' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '30': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:25' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '31': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:26' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '32': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:27' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '33': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:28' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '34': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:29' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '35': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:30' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '36': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:31' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '37': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:32' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '38': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:33' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '39': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:34' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '40': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:36' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '41': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:37' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '42': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:38' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '43': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:39' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '44': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:40' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '45': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:41' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '46': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:42' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '47': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:43' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '48': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:44' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '49': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:45' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '50': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:47' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '51': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:48' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '52': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:49' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '53': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:50' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '54': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:51' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '55': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:52' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '56': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:53' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '57': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:54' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '58': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:55' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '59': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:56' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '60': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:58' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '61': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:59' shape=(128,)dtype=int64>, '62': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:60' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '63': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:61' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '64': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:62' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '65': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:63' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '66': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:64' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '67': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:65' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '68': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:66' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '69': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:67' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '70': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:69' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '71': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:70' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '72': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:71' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '73': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:72' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '74': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:73' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '75': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:74' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '76': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:75' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '77': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:76' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '78': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:77' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '79': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:78' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '80': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:80' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '81': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:81' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '82': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:82' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '83': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:83' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '84': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:84' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '85': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:85' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '86': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:86' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '87': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:87' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '88': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:88' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '89': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:89' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '90': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:91' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '91': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:92' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '92': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:93' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '93': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:94' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '94': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:95' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '95': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:96' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>, '96': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:97' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>}.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you add your imports to your question?

Comment: Done, I added imports

Comment: Can you also provide some dummy data? Like 5 rows from your csv?

Comment: It would seem that your outputs are *strings*, and not numbers

Comment: Added some data on screenshot

Comment: I saw similar issue, but it doesnt really look clean for so many labels: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928272/error-in-constructing-multioutput-model-in-keras/70928674)

Comment: Add the data as text please.

Comment: I hope it is better now

Comment: Done, updated data

Comment: @AloneTogether any ideas? I can prepare a jupyer notebook if it is easier

Comment: Added to "How I load the dataset"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this dataset (based on the information in your question):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 97))).astype(int)
df['vectorizer_input'] = ['test hello world']*5
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

You could try something like this:

```py
tfdataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    '/content/test.csv', batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_epochs=1) # Do not forget num_epochs

def preprocess(data):
  labels = list(dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'vectorizer_input', data.items())).values())
  return data['vectorizer_input'], labels

tfdataset = tfdataset.map(preprocess)
vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=4000, output_sequence_length=4)
vectorizer.adapt(tfdataset.map(lambda x, y: x))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        vectorizer,
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(4000, 64),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(97, activation='sigmoid')
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model.fit(tfdataset.batch(2), epochs=10)
```

Comment: After i mapped dataset with preprocess function my dataset shape is the other way around <MapDataset shapes: ((None,), (97, None)), types: (tf.string, tf.int32)>

Comment: Did you run the example in my post?

Comment: I think it should be ((128, None), (128, 97))

Comment: Yes. I did run your example

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: No, with train_dataset.batch(2) in .fit() the error is: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 128.
And just with train_dataset in .fit() the error is: Incompatible shapes: [128,97] vs. [97,128]

Comment: Nope. Run the example in google colab. It is working.

Comment: Yes it works for 5 records, when i changed length of the dataset to 1000 and batch_size to 128 it gives the same error

Comment: Ok I see that batch_size in make_csv_dataset has to be 1, why?

Comment: Tested with 1000 samples. Still working.

Comment: Batch size is 1 for easier processing, you can change it later

Comment: Yeah if I changed batch_size argument in make_csv_dataset to 128 it gives an error